# How to transition smoothly and repeatedly between two videos using a command line tool on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, video, command-line, ffmpeg, video-editing

At first glance, this problem seems like it should be easy to solve, but I'm having difficulty locating the right solution on Ubuntu. I simply want to output a video using two videos as input, where these two videos fade into each other in a smooth and repetitive manner, every second or so. Would I be able to use something like ffmpeg for this task? If not, what's a typical efficient path to this goal?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.  For example, look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/637074/how-to-merge-multiple-more-than-two-videos-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you. I've reposted the question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116652/how-to-transition-smoothly-and-repeatedly-between-two-videos-using-a-command-lin if anyone wants to take a crack at it.